# Rounding transformation with Data Flow in Azure Data Factory is not working properly

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow, azure-sdk-.net

I’m currently creating Data flow with a Derived column that has a Rounding transformation through DontNet.SDK. The Source and Sink datasets I am using are parameterized. And I’m assigning values for them at runtime through pipeline parameters. Please refer below json files of two data flows.

[image]

I have a scenario which is rounding salary in to two decimal points from three decimal points. When I created this manually in ADF it’s successfully rounding. Below is the output result file of transformation

[image]

But when I am creating this using .net SDK, it’s not working. I’m not getting the column name as expected but the value is coming correctly. Below is the .SDK output

[image]

Below is the Json format of Data Flow I created

```
{
"name": "Rounding_Auto__Transformation",
"properties": {
    "type": "MappingDataFlow",
    "typeProperties": {
        "sources": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "defaultdataflowSourcedataset",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "source"
            }
        ],
        "sinks": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "defaultdataflowSinkdataset",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "sink"
            }
        ],
        "transformations": [
            {
                "name": "DerivedColumn0"
            }
        ],
        "script": "source(output(\n\t\tid as string,\n\t\tsal as string,\n\t\tgender as string,\n\t\tname as string,\n\t\tisMarried as string,\n\t\ttags as string,\n\t\taddress as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source\nsource derive(NewSal = round(toFloat(sal),2,2)) ~> DerivedColumn0\nDerivedColumn0 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tpartitionFileNames:['customer_post_with_round.csv'],\n\tpartitionBy('hash', 1),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink"
    }
}
```

}

I also compared the json created for the manual (as it works) in ADF directly– here is the one for manual

```
{
"name": "Rounding_Manually",
"properties": {
    "type": "MappingDataFlow",
    "typeProperties": {
        "sources": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "SourcDS",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "source1"
            }
        ],
        "sinks": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "SinkDS",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "sink1"
            }
        ],
        "transformations": [
            {
                "name": "DerivedColumn1"
            }
        ],
        "script": "source(output(\n\t\tid as string,\n\t\tsal as string,\n\t\tgender as string,\n\t\tname as string,\n\t\tisMarried as string,\n\t\ttags as string,\n\t\taddress as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1\nsource1 derive(NewSal = round(toFloat(sal),2,2)) ~> DerivedColumn1\nDerivedColumn1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tpartitionFileNames:['customer_post_with_round.csv'],\n\tpartitionBy('hash', 1),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1"
    }
}
```

}

Please help.

Comment: Can you compare the `Sink` dataset schema of both. It seems your dataset schema of the sdk case does not have the column header 'New sal' defined.

Comment: The JSON output crams the data flow script into a single line. Can you instead paste in the readable version of the script? There is a Script button on top of the ADF Data Flow designer UI.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, since I'm using parameterized datasets, the schema will be changed pipeline to pipeline but I'll try to bind the schema to dataset from the SDK. Will get back to you with the answer

Comment: @MarkKromer, this one I created manually in ADF,
source(output(
  id as string,
  sal as string,
  gender as string,
  name as string,
  isMarried as string,
  tags as string,
  address as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: false,
 ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1
source1 derive(NewSal = round(toFloat(sal),2,2)) ~> DerivedColumn1
DerivedColumn1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: false,
 partitionFileNames:['customer_post_with_round.csv'],
 partitionBy('hash', 1),
 skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
 skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1

Comment: This one I created through the SDK,
source(output(
  id as string,
  sal as string,
  gender as string,
  name as string,
  isMarried as string,
  tags as string,
  address as string,
  NewSal as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: false,
 ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source
source derive(NewSal = round(toFloat(sal),2,2)) ~> DerivedColumn0
DerivedColumn0 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: false,
 partitionFileNames:['customer_post_with_round.csv'],
 partitionBy('hash', 1),
 skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
 skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink

Comment: Please bare with me for the formatting, since can't add more character here

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, I added schema to dataset also, but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

I imported your data flow definition in my environment and I do see the column name in the metadata inspect and mapping list. Can you do the same and copy / paste the data flow script into the UI and make sure that you see everything there just fine?

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the same in my mapping also. but that new column is not saving in the destination file

Comment: Interesting. Can you create an Azure ticket on this? I'd like to have someone from engineering take a look to see if perhaps this is a valid bug.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the headers in the sink files were missing, and therefore they were not appearing the new ones during the transformation.
By adding the option First row as header issue is solved.